# Why use ないや instead of ない?

Tags: grammar

Not sure whether it's や or ないや that's the changed part anyone have more info on using this?

Comment: Please provide more context. No one will know how to answer the question as posted.

Comment: Let me guess... Are you living in the Osaka area?

Comment: や is a sentence-final particle that corresponds to だ/じゃ, and is used often in the Kansai and Hokuriku areas. Otherwise, it's just used to show an informal or friendly attitude and doesn't correspond to だ/じゃ. In the case of ないや, it seems be the latter case.

Comment: @ajsmart I live in Osaka and I have no clue what you hinted on. May I kindly ask you to elaborate? (within the context of ないや)

Comment: @macraf Isn't や something that is part of 関西弁？ For example: ほんまや、そうなんや、or せいやろ。

Comment: @ajsmart Did you read my comment before replying? (including the content in parentheses)

Comment: @macraf I'm not sure how to answer that, since Greek Fellows pretty much gave the answer I was hinting at.  Of course, there's no denying that I could be mistaken here.

Comment: @ajsmart Giving an example of a phrase you were hinting on? That would be a very good way to answer that, I guess. You could also reverse the reasoning and give an example of ないだ instead of ない in hyoujungo.

Comment: @macraf Ah, I see... Like... 「そんなことないや」とかね。関係ないかもしれないけど「わからんや」もあるけどね。Or were you looking for something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64051/discussion-between-ajsmart-and-macraf).

Comment: @ajsmart Thank you! It's the first time in my life I read そんなことないや. As I'm in Osaka now, that's a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: @macraf You'll hear them stick it on the end of random phrases.  It behaves kindof like the ね particle, but not really.

Comment: @ajsmart ちょっとも信じられないや

Comment: OP. Apologies for not providing better context, just heard it in passing, indeed from the Osaka area, and picked up on it. Greek Fellows and ajsmart nailed it. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 1):

If it's Osaka dialect instead of New Tokyo dialect just spoken in Osaka, you probably misheard ないんや{LHL} or なんや{LHL}？ (I'm not familiar with pitch pattern of Kansai dialects, so I might have mixed some of them), which corresponds with ないんだ{HL} and 何だ？ respectively.

The combination of ない and dialectal copula や is ungrammatical.

If it's really ないや{HL}, i.e ない with sentence ending particle や, it can't be an Osaka dialect, which would be ないわ then.

Sentence ender や stands for casual feel in giving up something. e.g やっぱ…いいや (No, thanks, after all...)

Comment: 「[ないやん]{LHLL}」（ないじゃないか）だったという可能性もあったりして・・？